# how to get data NOT IN next tabel mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql query that return all data

```
SELECT state,`County`,`CountyFIPS`,count(`email_address`) as email 
FROM `campaign_emails` 
Where state='AK' 
  AND CountyFIPS NOT IN 
   (select group_concat(`county_fipscode` separator ',') 
    from order_cart where flyer_id='1' AND user_id='400'
   ) 
GROUP BY `CountyFIPS`
```

But the same query when I manually pass it returns my exact value

```
SELECT state,`County`,`CountyFIPS`,count(`email_address`) as email 
FROM `campaign_emails` 
Where state='AK' 
  AND CountyFIPS NOT IN (02261,02220,02180,02170,02240,02020,02090,02110) 
GROUP BY `CountyFIPS`
```

please help anybody, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` accepts the results of a SELECT query but a string with comma-separated values as a hard-coded string is seen as 1 value only, so everything will match in your first query.

Mysql sees your condition in the first query as:

```
... AND CountyFIPS NOT IN ('1,2,3,4,5')    // this is not the array of values you want to use
```

So you can simplify your code to:

```
SELECT state,County,CountyFIPS,count(email_address) as email
FROM campaign_emails Where state='AK' 
    AND CountyFIPS NOT IN (select county_fipscode from order_cart where flyer_id='1' AND user_id='400') GROUP BY CountyFIPS
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here
```